# How do I specify new lines in a string in order to write multiple lines to a file?

Tags: python, line-breaks, file-writing

How can I indicate a newline in a string in Python, so that I can write multiple lines to a text file?

Comment: You do realise that Python's `print` works like `System.out.println` in Java, and automatically adds a newline after the text, right?

Comment: The `print` statement in Python can also be used to write to files (the details differ between Python 2.x and Python 3.x, so check with the reference docs for your version). [`print` in Python 2.x](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) - [`print` in Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#print)

Answer (score 488, accepted):

It depends on how correct you want to be. `\n` will usually do the job. If you really want to get it right, you look up the newline character in the [`os` package](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html). (It's actually called `linesep`.)

Note: when writing to files using the Python API, do not use the `os.linesep`. Just use `\n`; Python automatically translates that to the proper newline character for your platform.

Comment: From the link you provided "Do not use os.linesep as a line terminator when writing files opened in text mode (the default); use a single '\n' instead, on all platforms." So what do you mean by "right" and what are the reasons for their and your comment?

Comment: @Yasen: On Windows, the newline sequence is `"\r\n"`. This means that `os.linesep` will be `"\r\n"`. When you are writing to a file in text mode, it does newline translation as it writes; that is, each `"\n"` in the output will be translated to `"\r\n"` in the resulting file. You can see how this is a problem if the text that you're writing already contains `"\r\n"` sequences: the result will be `"\r\r\n"` at the end of every line. I assume, at least: I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: For a line break which is format-specific rather than OS-specific, e.g. an [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)-compliant CSV file uses \r\n, how would one do that if \n might be written out as \r\n, resulting in \r\r\n in the file?

Answer (score 126):

The new line character is `\n`. It is used inside a string.

Example:

```
    print('First line \n Second line')
```

where `\n` is the newline character.

This would yield the result:

```
First line
 Second line
```

If you use Python 2, you do not use the parentheses on the print function.

Answer (score 38):

**Platform-independent line breaker: Linux, Windows, and iOS**

```python
import os
keyword = 'physical'+ os.linesep + 'distancing'
print(keyword)
```

**Output:**

```
physical
distancing
```

Answer (score 31):

You can either write in the new lines separately or within a single string, which is easier.

## Example 1

### Input

```
line1 = "hello how are you"
line2 = "I am testing the new line escape sequence"
line3 = "this seems to work"
```

You can write the '\n' separately:

```
file.write(line1)
file.write("\n")
file.write(line2)
file.write("\n")
file.write(line3)
file.write("\n")
```

### Output

```
hello how are you
I am testing the new line escape sequence
this seems to work
```

## Example 2

### Input

As others have pointed out in the previous answers, place the \n at the relevant points in your string:

```
line = "hello how are you\nI am testing the new line escape sequence\nthis seems to work"

file.write(line)
```

### Output

```
hello how are you
I am testing the new line escape sequence
this seems to work
```

Answer (score 21):

Here is a more readable solution that will work correctly even if you aren't at top level indentation (e.g., in a function definition).

```
import textwrap
file.write(textwrap.dedent("""
    Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player
    That struts and frets his hour upon the stage
    And then is heard no more: it is a tale
    Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury,
    Signifying nothing.
"""))
```

Answer (score 14):

## Simplest solution

If you only call `print` without any arguments, it will output a blank line.

```
print
```

You can pipe the output to a file like this (considering your example):

```
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
print 'First line' >> f
print >> f
print 'Second line' >> f
f.close()
```

Not only is it OS-agnostic (without even having to use the `os` package), it's also more readable than putting `\n` within strings.

## Explanation

The `print()` function has an optional keyword argument for the end of the string, called `end`, which defaults to the OS's newline character, for eg. `\n`. So, when you're calling `print('hello')`, Python is actually printing `'hello' + '\n'`. Which means that when you're calling just `print` without any arguments, it's actually printing `'' + '\n'`, which results in a newline.

## Alternative

Use multi-line strings.

```
s = """First line
    Second line
    Third line"""
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
print s >> f
f.close()
```

Answer (score 11):

In Python you can just use the new-line character, i.e. `\n`

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in other answers: "The new line character is \n. It is used inside a string".

I found the most simple and readable way is to use the "format" function, using nl as the name for a new line, and break the string you want to print to the exact format you going to print it:

Python 2:

```
print("line1{nl}"
      "line2{nl}"
      "line3".format(nl="\n"))
```

Python 3:

```
nl = "\n"
print(f"line1{nl}"
      f"line2{nl}"
      f"line3")
```

That will output:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

This way it performs the task, and also gives high readability of the code :)

Answer (score 9):

The same way with `'\n'`, though you'd probably not need the `'\r'`. Is there a reason you have it in your Java version? If you do need/want it, you can use it in the same way in Python too.

Answer (score 7):

It is worth noting that when you inspect a string using the interactive Python shell or a [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter), the `\n` and other backslashed strings like `\t` are rendered **literally**:

```
>>> gotcha = 'Here is some random message...'
>>> gotcha += '\nAdditional content:\n\t{}'.format('Yet even more great stuff!')
>>> gotcha
'Here is some random message...\nAdditional content:\n\tYet even more great stuff!'
```

The newlines, tabs, and other special non-printed characters are rendered as whitespace **only when printed**, or written to a file:

```
>>> print('{}'.format(gotcha))
Here is some random message...
Additional content:
    Yet even more great stuff!
```

Answer (score 5):

Most escape characters in string literals from Java are also valid in Python, such as "\r" and "\n".

Answer (score 5):

\n - simple newline character insertion works:

```
# Here's the test example - string with newline char:
In [36]: test_line = "Hi!!!\n testing first line.. \n testing second line.. \n and third line....."
```

#### Output:

```
In [37]: print(test_line)

Hi!!!
 testing first line..
 testing second line..
 and third line.....
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, the language takes care of encoding newlines for you in the platform's native representation. That means `\r\n` on Windows, and just `\n` on grown-up systems.

Even on U*x systems, reading a file with Windows line endings in text mode returns correct results for text, i.e. any `\r` characters before the `\n` characters are silently dropped.

If you need total control over the bytes in the file, you can use binary mode. Then every byte corresponds exactly to one byte, and Python performs no translation.

```py
>>> # Write a file with different line endings, using binary mode for full control
>>> with open('/tmp/demo.txt', 'wb') as wf:
...     wf.write(b'DOS line\r\n')
...     wf.write(b'U*x line\n')
...     wf.write(b'no line')
10
9
7

>>> # Read the file as text
>>> with open('/tmp/demo.txt', 'r') as text:
...     for line in text:
...         print(line, end='')
DOS line
U*x line
no line

>>> # Or more demonstrably
>>> with open('/tmp/demo.txt', 'r') as text:
...     for line in text:
...         print(repr(line))
'DOS line\n'
'U*x line\n'
'no line'

>>> # Back to bytes!
>>> with open('/tmp/demo.txt', 'rb') as binary:
...     for line in binary:
...         print(line)
b'DOS line\r\n'
b'U*x line\n'
b'no line'

>>> # Open in binary, but convert back to text
>>> with open('/tmp/demo.txt', 'rb') as binary:
...     for line in binary:
...         print(line.decode('utf-8'), end='')
DOS line
U*x line
no line

>>> # Or again in more detail, with repr()
>>> with open('/tmp/demo.txt', 'rb') as binary:
...     for line in binary:
...         print(repr(line.decode('utf-8')))
'DOS line\r\n'
'U*x line\n'
'no line'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
"{}\n{}\n{}".format(
    "line1",
    "line2",
    "line3"
)
```

I personally prefer this format.

Answer (score 2):

\n  separates the lines of a string. In the following example, I keep writing the records in a loop. Each record is separated by `\n`.

```
f = open("jsonFile.txt", "w")

for row_index in range(2, sheet.nrows):

  mydict1 = {
    "PowerMeterId" : row_index + 1,
    "Service": "Electricity",
    "Building": "JTC FoodHub",
    "Floor": str(Floor),
    "Location": Location,
    "ReportType": "Electricity",
    "System": System,
    "SubSystem": "",
    "Incomer": "",
    "Category": "",
    "DisplayName": DisplayName,
    "Description": Description,
    "Tag": tag,
    "IsActive": 1,
    "DataProviderType": int(0),
    "DataTable": ""
  }
  mydict1.pop("_id", None)
  f.write(str(mydict1) + '\n')

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Various equivalent methods

#### Using `print`

`print` already appends a newline by default!

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    print("First", file=f)
    print("Second", file=f)
```

Equivalently:

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    print("First\nSecond", file=f)
```

To `print` *without* automatically adding a newline, use `sep=""` (since `sep="\n"` is the default):

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    print("First\nSecond\n", sep="", file=f)
```

---

#### Using `f.write`

For files opened in text mode:

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("First\nSecond\n")
```

For files opened in binary mode, the files will be written *without* automatic translation of `\n` to the platform-specific line terminator. To enforce the newline character for the current platform is used, use [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep) instead of `\n`:

```
with open("out.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write("First" + os.linesep)
    f.write("Second" + os.linesep)
```

---

#### Output file

Visually:

```
First
Second
```

On Linux, the newlines will be separated by `\n`:

```
First\nSecond\n
```

On Windows, the newlines will be separated by `\r\n`:

```
First\r\nSecond\r\n
```

To avoid automatic translation of `\n` to `\r\n` for files opened in text mode, open the file using [`open("out.txt", "w", newline="\n")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).