# How to use "\n" while writing to files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote python code to write to a file like this:

```
   with codecs.open("wrtieToThisFile.txt",'w','utf-8') as outputFile:
            for k,v in list1:
                outputFile.write(k + "\n")
```

The list1 is of type (char,int)
The problem here is that when I execute this, file doesn't get separated by "\n" as expected. Any idea what is the problem here ? I think it is because of the

```
with
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
(I am using Python 3.4 with "Python Tools for Visual Studio" version 2.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, from here:

[How would I specify a new line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/new-line-python)

I had to use "\r\n" as in Windows, "\r\n" will work.

Comment: Not very portable, use `os.linesep`, which will put the right line separator for whatever system you are on.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and it just prints os.linesep where I wanted the new line break. I am writing to a text file in windows. Even I want something portable.

Answer (score 10):

If you are on windows the `\n` doesn't terminate a line.
Honestly, I'm surprised you are having a problem, by default any file opened in text mode would automatically convert the `\n` to `os.linesep`. I have no idea what `codecs.open()` is but it must be opening the file in binary mode.
Given that is the case you need to explicitly add `os.linesep`:

```
outputFile.write(k + os.linesep)
```

Obviously you have to `import os` somewhere.

Comment: this is adding double lines

Comment: missing encoding="utf-8" is why it didnt do line breaks

Answer (score 3):

Per [`codecs.open`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open), `codecs.open` opens the underlying file in binary mode, without line ending conversion. Frankly, `codecs.open` is semi-deprecated; in Python 2.7 and onwards, `io.open` (which is the same thing as the builtin `open` function in Python 3.x) handles 99% of the cases people used to use `codecs.open`, but better (faster, and without stupid issues like line endings). If you're reliably running on Python 3, just use plain `open`; if you need to run on Python 2.7 as well, import `io` and use `io.open`.

Comment: I didn't just use codecs.open simply, it was for other requirement which otherwise won't decode my required file

Comment: Unless your file was in one of the pseudocodecs (`hex`, `rot13` and the like), `io.open` should handle it. It reads and writes non-ASCII-encoded files just fine; it's not Py2's default `open` where it would only read `str`, not `unicode`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, try '\r\n'. Or open it with an editor that recognizes unix style new lines.