# Python append new line to a string with in an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, append, newline

append new line to a string with in an array

```
result = []

str = ""

str = str + " this is my result for..."

result.append([x, y, str])
```

**output will be :**

```
[1, 2, this is my result for...], [12, 297, this is my result for...], [13, 42, this is my result for...], [34, 42, this is my result for...],[1345, 332, this is my result for...], [341, 244, this is my result for...]
```

**But i want the output to be :**

```
[1, 2, this is my result for...], 
[12, 297, this is my result for...], 
[13, 42, this is my result for...], 
[34, 42, this is my result for...],
[1345, 332, this is my result for...], 
[341, 244, this is my result for...]
```

Comment: `for line in result: print line`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/new-line-python)

Comment: result here is an array. result = []

Comment: To elaborate on what @jonrsharpe suggested. `result` is a list of lists and `print result` will print the list in one line. It is not a string and does not have newline characters. print adds a newline character after each call so you can loop through your list and print each element one at a time.

Comment: yes you are right. after every append in the list i want a new line so that the desired output is displayed as above

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pprint` to get a formatted output.

```
result = [
    ['this is my result for...', 1, 2],
    ['this is my result for...', 12, 297],
    ['this is my result for...', 13, 42]]

from pprint import pprint
pprint result
```

> [['this is my result for...', 1, 2],
>    ['this is my result for...', 12, 297],
>    ['this is my result for...', 13, 42]]

Or loop over the results as suggest by jonrsharpe:

```
result = [
    ['this is my result for...', 1, 2],
    ['this is my result for...', 12, 297],
    ['this is my result for...', 13, 42]]

for line in result: print line
```

> ['this is my result for...', 1, 2]
>    ['this is my result for...', 12, 297]
>    ['this is my result for...', 13, 42]