# How do I make text go on to the next line (enter/return effect)? Python

Tags: python, string, text, keyboard, enter

I have numerous strings which I am writing into a notepad txt.file via python using

```
x = open("File", "w")
```

However i want the strings to be written in the text file in the format:

```
('Hello')
('Hey')
('Whatever')
```

Instead of this:

```
('Hello')('Hey')('Whatever')
```

I'm missing specific code to achieve the 'keyboard enter/return' affect, so if anyone knows please drop me an answer. Also, I don't want to manually press enter in the actual text file, I want to do it via python. Thanks!

Comment: When you're writing to it, write a line break?

Comment: use a "\n" at the end of your string data.

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/new-line-python. Essentially you should use a new line character which is \n. "\" is an escape character.

Comment: thank you, just looked at the link, exactly what i wanted @USER_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd put my comment as an answer.

Here is a related question: [stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/new-line-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/new-line-python).

Essentially you should use a new line character which is `\n`. "`\`" is an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triple quotes to include the returns without using \n.

Like this

```
"""Line1
Line2
Line3
"""
```