# Having trouble understanding "\n" in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I dunno whats the purpose of this `\n` in `python`

Here is an example shown below:

```
 rangeNum = int(raw_input("Enter the max number you'd like to go up to: \n"))
```

Comment: It's a line break

Comment: Did you try removing it and see what happens?

Comment: It is not a Python specific character. Actually, it is an ASCII character. There is plenty of information on Internet

Comment: The direction of the slash is important.  `/n` is two characters, `\n` is one character, a new line

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-n-do-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/new-line-python

Comment: @Jalo:  Not all languages represent a line break as `\n`, so I would say it *is* Python specific.  ASCII certainly does not mandate that representation.  `\n` doesn't even map to a consistent ASCII character (it may be LF, CR+LF, or on older Macs, CR)

Comment: @MartinBonner: `\n` is a line feed (0x0a), `\r` is a carriage return (0x0d).

Comment: @Matthias is right. \n in Python maps to LF on Unix, and CR+LF on windows when writing to files. Except if you specify binary, then it's always LF.

Comment: In the context of file handling [_universal newlines_](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) has to be considered.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Yes, yes.  On Unix and on Windows  - but there are other operating systems out there, and there have been even more in the past.

Comment: @MartinBronner, I meant to say you're right. I just gave Windows and Linux as an example to Matthias to show that the \n isn't an exact mapping to ASCII characters in Python.

Comment: [But it is](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). Of course the Python documentation might be wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

> It is a special [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character signifying the end of a [line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(text_file)) of text and the start of a [new line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: ... and more of them that Python supports in its string literals can be found here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals    Scroll down to the 'Escape sequence' table.

Comment: In what way is it an ASCII character?

Comment: @MartinBonner: Because it's defined like that. Have a look at the [Table of Control Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters).

Comment: @Matthias:  I am pretty sure that Python will map `\n` to whatever the underlying C implementation uses for `\n`.  That may be LF, or on older Macs it may be CR.  I have no idea what it is on EBCDIC mainframes, it will be.  Saying that `\n` is **A** ASCII character is wrong.  "A special character signifying ... " would be fine.

Comment: According to the Python documentation the correct wording would be: [The meaning of `\n`is _ASCII Linefeed (LF)_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).