# Write to file .txt

Tags: python

This is how the output should look like in the text file

```
Ray Holt
5 5 0 0 100 15
Jessica Jones
12 0 6 6 50 6
Johnny Rose
6 2 0 4 20 10
Gina Linetti
7 4 0 3 300 15
```

The number is the result from the game that I have to create.

My question is, how can I write to the text file with both string and integer result ? 
I have tried this

```
def write_to_file(filename, player_list):
    output = open(filename, "w")    
    for player in player_list:
        output.write(str(player))
```

but the output is

```
Ray Holt                   5  5  0  0     100      15Jessica Jones             12  0  6  6      50      6Johnny Rose                6  2  0  4      20      10Gina Linetti               7  4  0  3     300      15Khang                      0  0  0  0     100       0
```

They are in 1 line

Please help me!
Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Also write a `'\n'` somewhere…

Comment: You need to close the file afterwards- `output.close()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/how-do-i-specify-new-lines-on-python-when-writing-on-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Comment: There is expected outcome described but nothing about how 'player_list' look like.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
def write_to_file(filename, player_list):
    output = open(filename, "w")    
    for player in player_list:
        output.write(str(player)+'\n')
output.close()
```

Comment: It doesnt work as I expect. The output should be a name line and then the number line then the name line and number line and so on

Comment: @KhangNguyen I don't know how player_list looks like. As such, I can't get a sample output. Please show at least some part of the list.