# How to make python go to the next line while writing in a txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a GUI where a button writes a certain string of text into the 'link_list' txt file. When this line of text is written it stays on the same line. I want the line of text, printed from the button, to go to a separate line each time it is printed

```
f = open('link_list.txt', 'a+')
f.write("test ")
f.close()
```

(I repeated the function 5 times to better show what i meant

Output:

```
test test test test test
```

Intended Output:

```
test
test
test
test
test
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify new lines on Python, when writing on files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/how-do-i-specify-new-lines-on-python-when-writing-on-files)

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend always using a context manager to handle file objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.  The easiest way is to write in a "\n" character when you want a "N"ew line.  The slash means whatever is next- is a special character.

replace

```
f.write("test ")
```

with this

```
f.write("test\n")
```

But I would start using pathlib for all your file writing needs:

```
from pathlib import Path
f = Path('link_list.txt')
with f.open("a"):
    f.write_text("test\n")
```

Comment: thanks, mate, I had seen the \n on some other forums but I couldn't find the syntax on how to use it. I'll accept this as the answer when the 6-minute time limit is up

Comment: TY.  I added info on pathlib.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a line feed character:

```
f = open('link_list.txt', 'a+')
f.write("test\n")
f.close()
```

even better with a context manager:

```
with open('link_list.txt', 'a+') as f:
    f.write("test\n")
```

This will ensure that your file is correctly closed even if an error occurs during the write operation.