# How can i send some Blank Line after headers in Python

Tags: python

```
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Smuggler/v1.0
Content-Length: 83

0

GET <URL> HTTP/1.1
X: X
```

as you can see in body i want to send some black line after Content-Length and after 0
i tried 
headers={'user-agent':'bot','\r\n'} adding \r\n after headers but it is not working
my code

```
import request 

url = "http://example.com" 
headers = {'user-agent':'firefox',\r\n ,'Content-type':'application/json'}
response = request.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: [Provide minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please!

Comment: import request

`url = "http://example.com"
headers = {'user-agent':'firefox',\r\n ,'Content-type':'application/json'}
response = request.get(url,headers=headers)`

Comment: Is it allowed in HTTP protocol?

Comment: yes it is allowed

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I had to provide the link here. [This shows how to add line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/how-do-i-specify-new-lines-on-python-when-writing-on-files). You didn't provide any code, which makes it difficult to provide the correct help.

Edit after seeing code:

You have to place `'\r\n'` or rather `'\n'` inside quote marks.

Example:

```py
a='\n'*3
print(f'hello{a}world')
### Outputs ###
# hello
# 
# 
# world
```

Comment: you can check previous comment

Comment: @RavindraPrajapati answer has been updated after reviewing your code.