# Multiline Printing in Python

Tags: python

im new to python. My code is written below, i want to know if there is any way of writing in a single print instead of  many print statements to get output like(with design)

---

- Car Company: Honda
- Model :City
- Year Of Manufacturing: 2004
- Color:Black

  ---

```
class car:
    def __init__(self,model,color):
        self.model=model
        self.color=color
    def carDetails(self):
        yearOfManufacturing=input("Enter Year of Manufacturing: ")
        carCompany='Honda'
        print("*********************************************")
        print("* Car Company: "+carCompany)
        print("* Model :"+self.model)
        print("* Year Of Manufacturing: " +yearOfManufacturing)
        print("* Color:" + self.color)
        print("*********************************************")
carObj=car('City','Black')
carObj.carDetails()
```

Comment: `\n` is the newline character. You can include it in the string you print to move on to the next line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify new lines on Python, when writing on files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/how-do-i-specify-new-lines-on-python-when-writing-on-files)

Comment: Kindly search before asking

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one line? Your current code is much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The `\n` character is for a new line in a string:

```
class car: 

    def __init__(self, model, color): 
        self.model = model 
        self.color = color 

    def carDetails(self):

        yearOfManufacturing = input("Enter Year of Manufacturing: ") 
        carCompany = 'Honda'

        print(f"****************************\n* Car Company: + {carCompany}\n* Model : {self.model}\n* Year Of Manufacturing: {yearOfManufacturing}\n* Color: {self.color}\n****************************")


carObj = car('City', 'Black')
carObj.carDetails()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using triple quotes with f-string notation for this:

```
print(
f"""
*********************************************
* Car Company: {carCompany}
* Model : {self.model}
* Year Of Manufacturing: {yearOfManufacturing}
* Color: {self.color}
********************************************
"""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` prints a new line.

e.g. `print("line1 \nline2")` will print

```
line1
line2
```