# Hwo to write newline without escape sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I wonder how to write `\n`, not using `\n`. What is the 'raw' way to write a new line?
Instead of

```
print("Hello\nWorld")
```

Output

```
Hello
World
```

I want

```
print("HelloSOMEENCODINGWorld)
```

Output

```
Hello
World
```

Is there a way to use ASCII, Hex, ... within the string?

Comment: What’s your end goal? You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1968).

Comment: @Stophface that edit dose not make the question any more clear. ASCII is an encoding, Hex is a numeral system. Why can't you use `\n`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bash ANSI Escape Sequences:

```py
print('Line1 \033[1B\033[50000DLine2',)
# \033[1B Gets cursor to the line below
# \033[50000D Gets the cursor 50000 spaces to the left , 50000 is just a random big number
```

You can refer [this](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) for more info on Bash ANSI Escape Sequences

Comment: So if I want to write 50001 characters to one line and then add a line break, this will not work properly. Also, when writing this to a file and opening the file in a text editor, it will give unexpected results. Really, why not just `\n` (more a question to @Stophface, not to @Atharva).

Comment: So … you’re now using three escape sequences (two Python-level escape sequences, and one terminal-level ANSI escape sequence) instead of one, and the result only works in highly specific circumstances. … I fail to see how this is an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi-line strings.

```
print("""Hello
World""")
```

But \n is better

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is `print('Hello{}World'.format(chr(10)))`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this might be through `os.linesep`

```
import os

print('This is a line with a line break\nin the middle')
print(f'This is a line with a line break {os.linesep}in the middle')
```

But as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11497391/15342707):

> Note: when writing to files using the Python API, do not use the os.linesep. Just use \n; Python automatically translates that to the proper newline character for your platform.