# how can i skip to the next line after each element in a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list with tuples of numbers being exponenciated such as this:

```
[(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32),
(3, 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243),
(4, 1, 4, 16, 64, 256, 1024),
(5, 1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125),
(6, 1, 6, 36, 216, 1296, 7776),
(7, 1, 7, 49, 343, 2401, 16807),
(8, 1, 8, 64, 512, 4096, 32768),
(9, 1, 9, 81, 729, 6561, 59049),
(10, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)]
```

I'm able to create the elements of this list using list comprehension, then appending them to an empty list but, the problem is that i dont know how to skip to the next line after each element.

my code is this:

```
def exponents(v):
    num = 0 
    listt = []
    while num < 11:
        exp = [num ** i for i in range(v)]
        exp.insert(0, num)
        listt.append(tuple(exp))
        num = num + 1
    return listt
print(exponents(6))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify new lines in a string in order to write multiple lines to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497376/how-do-i-specify-new-lines-in-a-string-in-order-to-write-multiple-lines-to-a-fil)

Answer (score 2):

If all you are trying to accomplish is printing each `tuple` on a separate line, you can do it by unpacking (`*`) the results and telling print that it's arguments should be separated by a new line.

```
def exponents(v):
    num = 0 
    listt = []
    while num < 11:
        exp = [num ** i for i in range(v)]
        exp.insert(0, num)
        listt.append(tuple(exp))
        num = num + 1
    return listt

print(*exponents(6), sep='\n')
```

Comment: how can i make so they all are on the same list?

Answer (score 1):

You are there already, its just a matter how you print it. To show each row individually you can use:

```
for row in exponents(6):
    print(row)
```

Comment: `print row` is not Python3 syntax

Comment: Yes of course, forgot the brackets sry